# How to exclude the second end from an enumerator

Tags: ruby, ienumerator

I need an `Enumerator` that iterates over `n` digits from `a` to `b - (b - a) / n.to_f()`. I need a left-closed right-open interval with step `(b - a) / n.to_f()`. How can I get it?

I use `a.step(b, (b - a) / n.to_f())`, but `step` returns an `Enumerator` that iterates over `n + 1` digits including both ends `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_steps(a,b,n)
  step = (b - a) / n.to_f
  a.step(b - step, step)   # or a.step(nil, step).take(n)
end

get_steps(2,4,5)       #=> <Enumerator:... >
get_steps(2,4,5).to_a  #=> [2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6]
```